# MySql 5.7. lock account after too many failed attempts

Tags: mysql, authentication, account

is there really no "build in" way to lock an mysql account (I use 5.7.15 on Debian) after a configured number of failed login attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there really no "build in" way to lock an mysql account

Not that I know off but you can get it done using application logic. That's: have a `bit` column named `IsLocked bit` and a `RetryCount INT` column. In your, application, check if it's subsequent login attempt and if it's then increase the `RetryCount` column.

Once, `RetryCount` column reaches to 3 (per your need) update the table set `IsLocked` column to `true`.

So, any login attempt after that; just check if the `IsLocked` column is `true` and if yes then deny the login and throw validation error message to end user.